# Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? Browser popup to avoid accidental tab closure while editing

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor, jce, front-end, browser-detection

Is there a way to force my browser (Chrome) when I edit (JCE) an article on frontend  to display a message preventing accidental tab closure or redirection?

I often make that mistake on to close a tab and lose all my work.

Sometime by clicking backward I can get back my work, but it often doesn't work.

Notice that I'm aware I should be careful where I click and that I should save often.

EDIT:

```
function getJavaScript($message) {


    $javascript .= 'if(window.addEventListener){ // Mozilla, Netscape, Firefox' . "\n";
    $javascript .= '    window.addEventListener("load", function(){ alert("' . $message . '");}, false);' . "\n";
    $javascript .= '} else { // IE' . "\n";
    $javascript .= '    window.attachEvent("onload", function(){ alert("' . $message . '");});' . "\n";
    $javascript .= '}';
    return $javascript;
}

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration( getJavaScript( 'Make sure you have saved your JCE content.' ) );
```

EDIT 2: C:My templates\protostar\html\com_content\form\edit.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_content
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('behavior.tabstate');
JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('behavior.calendar');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');
JHtml::_('behavior.modal', 'a.modal_jform_contenthistory');

// Create shortcut to parameters.
$params = $this->state->get('params');
//$images = json_decode($this->item->images);
//$urls = json_decode($this->item->urls);

// This checks if the editor config options have ever been saved. If they haven't they will fall back to the original settings.
$editoroptions = isset($params->show_publishing_options);
if (!$editoroptions)
{
    $params->show_urls_images_frontend = '0';
}
/// lodder code pour pop up front end
$js = '
    var needToConfirm = true;

    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        if (needToConfirm) {
            return "Make sure you have saved your JCE content";
        }
    }    
';


/// end lodder code pour pop up front end


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
        if (task == 'article.cancel' || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.getElementById('adminForm')))
        {
            <?php echo $this->form->getField('articletext')->save(); ?>
            Joomla.submitform(task);
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="edit item-page<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx; ?>">
    <?php if ($params->get('show_page_heading', 1)) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            <?php echo $this->escape($params->get('page_heading')); ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&a_id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" class="form-validate form-vertical">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.save')">
                    <span class="icon-ok"></span>&#160;<?php echo JText::_('JSAVE') ?>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.cancel')">
                    <span class="icon-cancel"></span>&#160;<?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL') ?>
                </button>
            </div>
            <?php if ($params->get('save_history', 0)) : ?>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <?php echo $this->form->getInput('contenthistory'); ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#editor" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_CONTENT') ?></a></li>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_urls_images_frontend') ) : ?>
                <li><a href="#images" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_IMAGES_AND_URLS') ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <li><a href="#publishing" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHING') ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="#language" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo JText::_('JFIELD_LANGUAGE_LABEL') ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="#metadata" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_METADATA') ?></a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="editor">
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('title'); ?>

                    <?php if (is_null($this->item->id)) : ?>
                        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('alias'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('articletext'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_urls_images_frontend')): ?>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="images">
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('image_intro', 'images'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('image_intro_alt', 'images'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('image_intro_caption', 'images'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('float_intro', 'images'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('image_fulltext', 'images'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('image_fulltext_alt', 'images'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('image_fulltext_caption', 'images'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('float_fulltext', 'images'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('urla', 'urls'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('urlatext', 'urls'); ?>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('targeta', 'urls'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('urlb', 'urls'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('urlbtext', 'urls'); ?>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('targetb', 'urls'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('urlc', 'urls'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('urlctext', 'urls'); ?>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('targetc', 'urls'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="publishing">
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('catid'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('tags'); ?>
                    <?php if ($params->get('save_history', 0)) : ?>
                        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('version_note'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('created_by_alias'); ?>
                    <?php if ($this->item->params->get('access-change')) : ?>
                        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('state'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('featured'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('publish_up'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('publish_down'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('access'); ?>
                    <?php if (is_null($this->item->id)):?>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="control-label">
                            </div>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ORDERING'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="language">
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('language'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="metadata">
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('metadesc'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('metakey'); ?>

                    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $this->return_page; ?>" />
                    <?php if ($this->params->get('enable_category', 0) == 1) :?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="jform[catid]" value="<?php echo $this->params->get('catid', 1); ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following Javascript which will bring up a alert box asking if you want to leave the page or stay on it when you go to close a browser tab.

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return 'Make sure you have saved your JCE content';
    }
</script>
```

If you're wondering where to add your code, you can either:

1. Add it to your admin template index.php file, however this is a core hack to any template updates will override this change.
2. You can create a small [Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Plugin_Development) which executes this code.
3. Create a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for com_content view and inject the above code into the head using Joomla's `addScriptDeclaration()` function.

### Update:

```
$js = '
    var needToConfirm = true;

    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        if (needToConfirm) {
            return "Make sure you have saved your JCE content";
        }
    }    
';
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Comment: This code would have to be added only when the article is being edited. If it is generically added without detection for JCE it will alert the user even if they are a guest/member. Although detection for a super user could get around all of it.

Comment: @lodder Thanks! Jordan is right, this script alerts even when a simple visitor navigate on my website. Is there a way to make this alert appear only when an article is edited on front-end?

Comment: Sorry, when I said template index.php, I was referring to your admin template, not the frontend one ;) I've updated my answer with another option too

Comment: @Lodder I could find the administrator/components/com_content folder but I am not sure in which file I am suppose to add the code. Is it: administrator/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php ?

Comment: `com_content\views\article\tmpl\edit.php`, however as mentioned in my answer, you should create a template override rather than edit the core file

Comment: I have created the override, and added the code (see the edit in my question) in the  `administrator\templates\isis\html\com_content\article\edit.php `    at the line 63 (just before  `   ?> `   . (I couldn't find a  ` head `    tag in this file). I have edit the code following the instructions  on this page  `http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScriptDeclaration `    about the   `   addScriptDeclaration() function

Comment: @lodder Thanks for your patience, as you noticed I'm not really comfortable with the addScriptDeclaration() function and php...

Comment: I see you made a little mistake. You need to use quotes inside the addScriptDeclaration function. I've updated my answer based on your code with some minor tweak aswell to make it look a little cleaner. Hope this helps

Comment: The code in my question was displaying a message when the article editing page has just finish to load but not when I try to quit it (and this happens only on backend, but not on frontend editing). I've tried with your code and nothing seems to happen on the frontend nor backend.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with what I said before. I will give your code a test in a bit. Bare with me :)

Comment: Sorry to go back to you @Lodder. Have you found the mistake you made?

Comment: @Giim - oops, sorry, completely forgot about this. Will test now

Comment: @Giim - Right, I've updated my code again and tested it. I've tested this in the backend but Im sure it will apply for the frontend too. When I made changes to some content and tried to close the tab, the alert popped up. Hope this works for you too

Comment: @Lodder I test it. The message appear only when I load the article edit page but not when it should: it doesn't prevent me from quitting the article edit page if I click on a link by mistake. Also the pop up doesn't appear on front end. Is the front end article layout generated by the administrator template?  Are you sure about the "load" event?

Comment: You need to add the code to `components/com_content/views/form/edit.php` but of course as mentioned before, you should create a Template Override

Comment: Don't worry about the override, I always do it that way. So now, I have the pop up showing up only on front-end but it's still appearing when the article edit page is loading  (btw it prevent the page from loading, and I have to click yes, for JCE editor to appear) and it still doesn't show up to prevent me from navigating away to a link on which I've click by mistake. Any idea why?

Comment: @Giim - Can you try the updated code in my answer please

Comment: @Lodder, I've just tried it, nothing happens.

Comment: Which browser + version are you using? Please oh please don't say Internet Explorer

Comment: No, I use Chrome. version 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: @Lodder, I've just tried on Firefox version 30.0 and also there nothing happens

Comment: That's extremely odd cause I'm testing on FF and it works perfectly fine for me. I'll give it a go in chrome in a bit

Comment: Just to make sure. I have added your code in your answer below update in \templates\protostar\html\com_content\form\edit.php (the override file) at the line  31 (just before the `?>` )

Comment: @Giim - I have done exactly the same as you. Added the code in my answer to the same file as you have and it works. Just to let you know, you need to make a change to the article before trying to close the tab. Only then will the confirmation box appear.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @Lodder I did try on both chrome and FF,  open on front end the article, edit the content (add a word somewhere), and then close the tab/ click on one of my bookmark but still no pop up. I have added in my question the code of my templates\protostar\html\com_content\form\edit.php file under EDIT 2. Also I am using joomla 3.3.1

Comment: Thank so much! Actually, I should have payed more attention instead of copy pasting. Sorry for wasting you time and again thanks a thousand times!

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to add js script with a module called Jumi , set which pages to appear on and the permissions to limit it to editors or administrators only. 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/1023